# Global type doesn't work in Webstorm

Tags: intellij-idea, flowtype

I started using Flow with webstorm and IDE can't intercept global type which I declared (while flow compiler doesn't complain).

**flow-typed/libDefs.js**

```
// @flow
import type { UI } from 'data/redux/redux.flow';
declare var module: {
  hot:? {
    accept(reducers:? string, func:? Function): any,
  }
};

declare type State = {| //btw. eslint gives me here error 'no-undef' State is not defined
  +ui: UI,
|}
```

**src/data/redux/reducers/ui.js**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known issue, please follow [WEB-27102](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27102) for updates.